# Unit testing DAO tier with FUSE ESB

Tags: jpa, dao, fuseesb, blueprint-osgi

We are working on some spikes using Fuse ESB (Camel,OSGi, blueprint) to deliver some components. We have an imposed architecture from our EAs which is:  REST controller uses a route to call a CXF WS. This calls a local java class as a service to, for example, perform CRUD actions. These use JPA enabled DAO/entities. All seems a  bit academic in design rather than real world but thats *another* story.

Question is about testing. Normally I would actually test this service tier using H2 to provide the DB, wiring the DAO,  entityManager etc together with spring (I know some wouldn't do this but I do, bear with me). But we will use blueprint for fuse. How can I unit test this tier? Getting my tests to subclass CamelBlueprintTestSupport doesn’t work, this expects a route. Can’t use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner (though do have it working with this currently) as this wires with spring, when running in the container we will wire with blueprint.

So how do we unit test this? How do I instantiate this set of classes within a blueprint based unit test? Can we?

Answer (score 0):

One aproach you may try is to use [pax exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Pax+Exam). It allows to run tests in a full OSGi environment. So you can install your real bundle test it in a black box fashion.

Comment: Guess I was trying to avoid a full env. I actually have this working with spring, but without using annotations. That means no spring code is added to the classes, so I can keep spring as a test dep only. seems to work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use pojosr which is what camel-test-blueprint is using: https://code.google.com/p/pojosr/

Though pojosr is not a full OSGi environment, so there will be some limitations what you can do.

For the camel-test-blueprint you may be able to override the method isUseRouteBuilder and return false, then it ought not to expect a route.

Comment: I'll have a look at the library, but the override seems to have no effect. Thanks anyway - at least got some response here, nothing to this enquiry on the dedicated fuse forums...

Comment: FuseSource was acquired by Red Hat so use the Red Hat JBoss forums as also mentioned on the old fusesource web site.